# Scrolling TextView in custom alert dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to get my textview to scroll in my custom alert dialog, I cant seem to get it to work. I have an image and title + close button, then below the scrolling textview I have three buttons inside a table.
Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relViewTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/titleImg" android:src="@drawable/redpin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titleImg"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:textColor="#fffafa" android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnClose" android:text="Close"
        android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#fffafa" />

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip" android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="7" android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip" android:textColor="#fffafa" />
  </ScrollView>


    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableBtns"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDialPrev" android:text="Previous"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDialOk" android:text="ok"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDialNext" android:text="Next"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Where does your LinearLayout ends??

Answer (score 1):

Why should it scroll? You have set maxLines to 7 and the height to wrap_content, so it will always take as much space as it needs to display all its content.

Comment: I thought max lines would force it to scroll at that length of lines, I needed to add 'android:fillViewport="true"' to get it to work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, its a display height parameter:  public void  setMaxLines  (int maxlines)     Since: API Level 1

Makes the TextView at most this many lines tall. Setting this value overrides any other (maximum) height setting.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Create Normal XML, and call it when you want to display the alert dialog using new class.

alertbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i = new Intent(fromclassname.this, AlertDialog.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Call the the your.XML from AlertDilog.class

Finally in Manifest.XML, 
in **activity** declare 
**android:name=".AlertDilog"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"**